# Migrate struts action to spring action

Tags: spring, refactoring, struts, struts-action

I am looking for a good tutorial on migrating from struts to spring. I have multiple struts actions that I would like to refactor into spring components.

Answer (score 1):

[Here's one](http://www.devx.com/Java/Article/29208) (assuming you're talking about Struts 1, although you don't specify).

Not sure how helpful it will be; depending on how clean the original Struts code was it could be relatively straight-forward, or brutal.

In my experience the bulk of the work lies in the JSPs, not the actions themselves, particularly if the S1 code made extensive use of the Struts tags. The actions themselves are easier to deal with because of strong IDE support.